# Spock strict async interactions

Tags: mocking, spock

I need to verify that a method is called once with certain arguments and only called once (strict)
Basically I need the async version of this:

```java
1 * mockedClosure.call(1) //== page number
0 * mockedClosure.receive(*_)
```

I tried using AsyncConditions for this. Verifying the first method call works, but I don't know how to verify that no other calls occur.

```java
def conds = new AsyncConditions()
//expect:
subscriber.registerCallback({ int page ->
    conds.evaluate({
        assert page == 1
    })        
})
```

---

**Update:** I have implemented a Tiled Renderer which renders Tiles in the background on a single worker thread. The user can scroll and Tiles can become visible while there are still Tiles that need to be rendered. In my current implementation Tiles are rendered also if they are not visible anymore. I need a test that verifies that Tiles from the Queue/List aren't rendered if they have become invisible.

Code needed to be tested:

```java
fun tileVisible(args) {
    threadPool.submit {
        val bitmap = it.renderer.renderTile(args)
        it.tileRenderCache.addTile(args)
    }
}
```

TestCase:

```java
def conds = new AsyncConditions()
//expect:
realworldRenderer.registerRenderCallback({ page ->
    conds.evaluate({
        assert page == 1
    })
})

when: "the renderer is busy rendering a Tile" (in another thread)
tileRenderController.handleTileVisibilityChanged(eventPage1Visible)

and: "the second tile becomes visible" (called from the main thread)
tileRenderController.handleTileVisibilityChanged(eventPage2Visible)

and: "the second tile becomes invisible" (called again from the main thread)
tileRenderController.handleTileVisibilityChanged(eventPage2NotVisible)

then: "the first tile has been rendered and the second was skipped"
conds.await()
```

Comment: How about some application code also? It is hard to find out what the heck you are trying to test.

Comment: @kriegaex Added some Code and explanation

Comment: Maybe someone else can answer the question with this information, I cannot, still too many jigsaw puzzle pieces missing. I cannot see how the events work, how all the classes you show snippets of are defined etc. With an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) I might have been able to help. But if your problem is not reproduceable, I cannot check if my solution is working for you. Last, but not least, your application code seems to be something other than Groovy or Java. Kotlin maybe?

Comment: @Diemex have you solved this? Looking for the same solution